# How can I fix "E: Unable to locate package python" in termux?

Tags: python, termux

I am installing Python in [Termux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termux), but I am getting this error:

```
pkg install python
```

Output:

```
Checking availability of current mirror: ok
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
E: Unable to locate package python
```

Answer (score 19):

I think you haven't updated the repository. It looks like you have just installed Termux. Anyway, execute

```
apt update
```

and then install any package.

Answer (score 16):

The following combination of answers from this post worked for me:

1. `termux-setup-storage`
2. `termux-change-repo` (I selected Albatros)
3. `pkg update` and `pkg upgrade`
4. `exit` and then restart termux
5. `pkg install python -y`

Comment: Albatros, A1batros, A1batross, or Albatross?

Answer (score 13):

Termux has halted all updates through [Google Play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play). Download it from [F-Droid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-Droid).
Then change the mirror. It works (sometimes).

```
termux-change-repo
```

Or change it manually by editing the *sources.list* file in directory *$PREFIX/etc/apt*.

Check out my blog post for more [links](http://th3cr00k3dm4n.unaux.com/blog/how-to-change-termux-mirror/).

Answer (score 7):

Download it from [F-Droid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-Droid) instead of [Google Play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play).

The link is *https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.termux/.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have an Internet connection, and then allow access to your storage.

Run `termux-setup-storage`. This should ask you for permissions to allow termux to use your device storage.

Then to confirm storage is accessible, run `ls ~/storage/shared` to list directories contained in shared storage.

If this doesn't work, try switching repositories as some other answers suggest, as the node you're on may be down.

Comment: Hi ruzor and welcome to SO. Maybe you can show in your answer more details about the output of these commands :) . Anyway I think would be nice if you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

Try to upgrade your Termux via `pkg upgrade`. Then it finds the packages on [pkg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_Packaging_System).

Answer (score 1):

Only for mobile Termux:

```
termux-change-repo
```

There might be services for game and science needed to select all the three options and select the A1batross's options, thereby completing all the permission process steps.

Once done with all these steps, you can install and do operation as a Linux terminal.

PS: update the apt would be better before any other steps

Answer (score 0):

I changed my Termux repository to A1batross'.

Comment: Can you elaborate? It is too close to [Albatross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albatross_(disambiguation)) to give any meaningful search results. For example, where did you change it? Exactly how did you change it? Does it actually contain the number "1"?

Comment: [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65210662/how-to-fix-e-unable-to-locate-package-python-on-termux/71097459#71097459) uses Albatross, not A1batross.

Answer (score -1):

Just give storage permissions and restart the application. It worked fine for me.