# Termux. How to fix: Unable to locate package airmon-ng

Tags: termux

After full update/upgrade, tried to change repo... I saw different guide but still nothing...

THIS'S WHAT I DO

~ $ pkg install airmon-ng

Checking availability of current mirror:

[*] https://termux.librehat.com/apt/termux-main: ok

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... Done

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package airmon-ng

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "E: Unable to locate package python" on termux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65210662/how-to-fix-e-unable-to-locate-package-python-on-termux)

Answer (score 0):

it's because termux's owner removed it from repo, you can install it on https://github.com/pitube08642/aircrack-ng-for-termux

Answer (score 0):

You made one mistake, they actually removed aircrack-ng from the repo, but it was not installed with "apt install airmon-ng" but with "apt install aircrack-ng".